# Trouble with realization Byte[] operations

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, boolean-logic

I use XOR operation for byte[]

```
public static byte[] XOR(byte[] buffer1, byte[] buffer2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer1.Length; i++)
        buffer1[i] ^= buffer2[i];
    return buffer1;
}
```

And realize shift methods for hashing algorithm.

```
public static byte[] RotHi(byte[] B, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        byte[] a = ShHi(B);
        byte[] b = B;
        for (int j = (B.Length * 8) - 2; j >=0 ; j--)
        {
            b = ShLo(b);
        }
        B = XOR(a,b);
    }
    return B;
}
public static byte[] ShHi(byte[] B)
{
    return BitConverter.GetBytes(BitConverter.ToUInt64(B, 0) >> 1);
}
public static byte[] ShLo(byte[] B)
{
    return BitConverter.GetBytes(BitConverter.ToUInt64(B, 0) << 1);
}
```

And when it works individually result is correct

```
W0 = b194bac80a08f53b.
W1 = e12bdc1ae28257ec.
W2 = e9dee72c8f0c0fa6.
m1 = 8; n1 = 53.

T0 = RotHi(W0, m1); // 3bb194bac80a08f5
W0 = XOR(W0,W1);
W0 = XOR(W0,W2); // b96181fe6786ad71
```

But next code return wring result^

```
T1 = XOR(W1,(RotHi(W0, n1))); // ed242f26d7e9da27, but should be CDFB23D652B779DB
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What does this has to do with C++? You are clearly not programming in C++, so please don't add unrelated language tags.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger? When and where do the values you expect and the values you get start to deviate? Are you sure the expected value is correct? Are you sure your algorithm is correct?

Comment: you use n1 instead of m1 and do only the first xor not the second, so the answer will be different. Please make the two calculations equivalent before you complain about them giving two different answers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, I don't. But results T0 and W0 is right.

Comment: @prof1990 it's not equivalent, it's different variables and different operations. But only in third result is wrong ( reference is in standart)

Comment: What makes you think that the result should be what you think it should be? Is it something you calculated, or is it a given answer you are supposed to match?

Comment: @Abion47 It's a given answer I'm supposed to match. I have national standard.

Comment: write it down as individual lines, then if it is still wrong your algorithm has an issue. present two pieces of code that should be equivalent in your eyes but produce different results and maybe we can help.

Comment: Are you designing your algorithm based on instructions? If so, what are those instructions?

Comment: @Abion47 It's "СТБ 34.101.77" based on sponge functions and call bash. If you can help I'll send to you this doc

Comment: I'm getting a different result for `T0` and `T1` (`94bac80a08f53bb1` and `6ce0d11116bd6480` respectively). Can you show us your actual working code? Also, note that `XOR` is modifying its first argument - that's unexpected behavior given its signature. It may be causing problems.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet you a right!! I found it. But can't understand how to fix it.

Comment: Create a new array inside `XOR`, assign the xor results to that array (`newArray[i] = buffer1[i] ^ buffer2[i];`) and return that array instead of `buffer1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble was in byte sequence. Be attentive with BigEndian or LittleEndian.